# Skype notification tray icon is not showing on the topbar

Tags: wingpanel, skype

No tray icon for skype is visible. I mean on ubuntu it used to show a green icon whenever I'm online, yellow for away and red for busy.

Comment: before asking a question I recommend you to use the search option above, because no one wants to answer one and the same question again and again and again. chec this link https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/search?q=no+tray+icon

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the mistakes though.

Comment: Its totally okay @JahidulHasanHemal, mistakes are meant to happen. Have a nice day!